# Embed Unity into UWP Application

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

Is it possible to embed a Unity application (3D or 2D scene) into a UWP application? I'd like to render a 3D map (and possible a 2D version) in Unity, but have this displayed in a UWP application I'm developing. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should check "Atmosphere" example from [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/15/unity-interop-and-app-extensibility-app-dev-on-xbox-series/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the .Net scripting backend for Unity to solve a similar problem. (The atmosphere sample is barely documentated, and the scripting backend does the same job and the Unity docs are quite informative.) I posted the full answer here: [UWP app - unity 3d container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854722/uwp-app-unity-3d-container/49141089#49141089)